# Is there any information on what numbers of American families have what numbers of children, for any time period?

Tags: demography, resource

Is there any information on what numbers of American families have what numbers of children, for any time period?

Like, "How many families / couples have more than 7 kids, in 1950?"

'Cause all the info I've found in a cursory search gives me "3 kids +"...

I suppose this could be answered by giving me raw census data, but I'm not sure that's ever given out...

Comment: "Raw census data" is never given out (at least until > 100 years later), but aggregated census data is widely available in Western democracies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download Census microdata at IPUMS USA here: https://usa.ipums.org/usa/

Since a large number of births occurred to married women historically in the United States, you could also use completed birth parities by birth cohort of women for an estimation: cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/cohort_fertility_tables.htm

Comment: I suppose there's nothing that doesn't need me to sign up?

Comment: Since a large number of births occurred to married women historically in the United States, you could also use completed birth parities by birth cohort of women for an estimation: https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/cohort_fertility_tables.htm

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to add that to your answer?